# Why doesn't C# infer my generic types?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, type-inference

I'm having lots of Funcy fun (fun intended) with generic methods. In most cases C# type inference is smart enough to find out what generic arguments it must use on my generic methods, but now I've got a design where the C# compiler doesn't succeed, while I believe it could have succeeded in finding the correct types.

Can anyone tell me whether the compiler is a bit dumb in this case, or is there a very clear reason why it can't infer my generic arguments?

Here's the code:

Classes and interface definitions:

```
interface IQuery<TResult> { }

interface IQueryProcessor
{
    TResult Process<TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query)
        where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>;
}

class SomeQuery : IQuery<string>
{
}
```

Some code that does not compile:

```
class Test
{
    void Test(IQueryProcessor p)
    {
        var query = new SomeQuery();

        // Does not compile :-(
        p.Process(query);

        // Must explicitly write all arguments
        p.Process<SomeQuery, string>(query);
    }
}
```

Why is this? What am I missing here?

Here's the compiler error message (it doesn't leave much to our imagination):

> The type arguments for method IQueryProcessor.Process<TQuery,
> TResult>(TQuery) cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the
> type arguments explicitly.

The reason I believe C# should be able to infer it is because of the following:

1. I supply an object that implements `IQuery<TResult>`.
2. That only `IQuery<TResult>` version that type implements is `IQuery<string>` and thus TResult must be `string`.
3. With this information the compiler has TResult and TQuery.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what `TResult` to use. At the time it needs to make the decision, it doesn't know that you're going to put it into a `string` (so maybe it should infer `string`). And even if it knew, it could also legally be `Process<SomeQuery, customClass>` where `customClass` is any class derived from `string`. See also: [Return type inference doesn't work on member groups](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-member-groups.aspx).

Comment: @Raymond: Return types have nothing to do with this. See my update. I would expect the compiler `TResult` as a `string`, becaue the supplied object implements `IQuery<string>`.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thanks for the shout-out Raymond, but that is not the relevant article for this problem. The relevant article is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx

Comment: @Steven Do you remember how you fixed this constraint? did you go with a pile of generic parameters or called the method via reflection?

Comment: @trailmax: Absolutely. The solution is actually to use some dynamic typing. I wrote this down [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92). Just take a look at the `IQueryProcessor` interface and `QueryProcessor` implementation that I described in that article.

Comment: @Steven oh! I've done pretty much the same, was hoping for a new answer -). And it's great coincidence, because I've already commented on that blog entry!

Comment: You can workaround this limitation with some trick - http://joelabrahamsson.com/a-neat-little-type-inference-trick-with-c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>This was originally posted in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8511066/8) and moved here on the OP's behalf.</sup>

For me the best solution was to change the `IQueryProcessor` interface and use dynamic typing in the implementation:

```
public interface IQueryProcessor
{
    TResult Process<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query);
}

// Implementation
sealed class QueryProcessor : IQueryProcessor {
    private readonly Container container;

    public QueryProcessor(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public TResult Process<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query) {
        var handlerType =
            typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));
        dynamic handler = container.GetInstance(handlerType);
        return handler.Handle((dynamic)query);
    }
}
```

The `IQueryProcessor` interface now takes in a `IQuery<TResult>` parameter. This way it can return a `TResult` and this will solve the problems from the consumer's perspective. We need to use reflection in the implementation to get the actual implementation, since the concrete query types are needed (in my case). But here comes dynamic typing to the rescue which will do the reflection for us. You can read more about this in this [article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Answer (score 71):

A bunch of people have pointed out that C# does not make inferences based on constraints. That is correct, and relevant to the question. Inferences are made by examining *arguments* and their corresponding *formal parameter types* and that is the only source of inference information.

A bunch of people have then linked to this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-method-groups

That article is both out-of-date and irrelevant to the question. It is out-of-date because it describes a design decision we made in C# 3.0 which we then reversed in C# 4.0, mostly based on the response to that article. I've just added an update to that effect to the article.

It is irrelevant because the article is about *return type inference from method group arguments to generic delegate formal parameters*. That is not the situation the original poster asks about.

The relevant article of mine to read is rather this one:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature

UPDATE: I have heard news that C# 7.3 has slightly changed the rules for when constraints are applied, making the above ten-year-old article no longer accurate. When I have time I'll review the changes my former colleagues have made and see if it is worthwhile to post a correction on my new blog; until then, use caution and see what C# 7.3 does in practice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (THE answer). Is it possible for the C# compiler to do constraint inference in the future, or is that out of the question?

Comment: I'd say that having such inference is out of the question.  Eric states in a comment, "This is a deliberate design choice in accordance with the long-standing principles of the design of the C# language."

Comment: @Steven: Brian is correct; we don't have any intention of adding constraints to the list of facts that are used to make inferences.

Comment: @EricLippert: considering your update about C# 7.3, I am very interested in reading more on this topic.

Comment: AFAIK the only thing that changed re type constraints in C# 7.3 was that `unmanaged`, `Delegate`, `MulticastDelegate`, and `Enum` are now allowed (these were always permitted in the CLR, just not the C# language itself). The only other potential applicable change is that method overload resolution was improved to better disambiguate between multiple candidates.

Answer (score 19):

C# will not infer generic types based on the return type of a generic method, only the arguments to the method.

It also doesn't use the constraints as part of the type inference, which eliminates the generic constraint from supplying the type for you.

For details, see [Eric Lippert's post on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't use constraints to infer types. Rather it infers types (when possible) and then checks constraints.

Therefore, while the only possible `TResult` that could be used with a `SomeQuery` parameter, it won't see this.

Note also, that it would be perfectly possible for `SomeQuery` to also implement `IQuery<int>`, which is one reason why this is limitation on the compiler may not be a bad idea.

Answer (score 7):

I won't go into the why again, I have no illusions of being able to do a better explanation than Eric Lippert.

However, there is a solution that doesn't require late binding or extra parameters to your method call. It's not super intuitive however, so I'll leave it to the reader to decide if it's an improvement.

First off, modify `IQuery` to make it self-referencing:

```
public interface IQuery<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery: IQuery<TQuery, TResult>
{
}
```

Your `IQueryProcessor` would look like this:

```
public interface IQueryProcessor
{
    Task<TResult> ProcessAsync<TQuery, TResult>(IQuery<TQuery, TResult> query)
        where TQuery: IQuery<TQuery, TResult>;
}
```

An actual query type:

```
public class MyQuery: IQuery<MyQuery, MyResult>
{
    // Neccessary query parameters
}
```

An implementation of the processor might look like:

```
public Task<TResult> ProcessAsync<TQuery, TResult>(IQuery<TQuery, TResult> query)
    where TQuery: IQuery<TQuery, TResult>
{
    var handler = serviceProvider.Resolve<QueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>>();
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The spec lays this out pretty clearly:

> Section 7.4.2 Type Inference
>
> **If the supplied number of arguments is different than the number of parameters in the method, then inference immediately fails.** Otherwise, assume that the generic method has the following signature:
>
> Tr M(T1 x1 … Tm xm)
>
> With a method call of the form M(E1 …Em) the task of type inference is to **find unique type arguments S1…Sn for each of the type parameters X1…Xn so that the call M(E1…Em)becomes valid.**

As you can see, the return type is not used for type inference.  If the method call does not map directly to the type arguments inference immediately fails.

The compiler does not just assume that you wanted `string` as the `TResult` argument, nor can it.  Imagine a `TResult` derived from string.  Both would be valid, so which to choose?  Better to be explicit.

Comment: It's not only the return type that would make type inference succeed. The type implements `IQuery<string>`.

Comment: Notice also that the first highlighted statement is an error; this line was never updated when we added named and optional arguments, and also is inconsistent with type inference on "params" methods applicable in their expanded form. A future version of the specification will correct the line to take those into account.

Comment: FWIW, the quoted section 7.4.2 seems to correspond to 12.6.3.1 of [the 5th edition of the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

The **why** has been well answered but there is an alternative solution. I face the same issues regularly however `dynamic` or any solution using reflection or allocating data is out of question in my case (joy of video games...)

So instead I pass the return as an `out` parameters which is then correctly inferred.

```
interface IQueryProcessor
{
     void Process<TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query, out TResult result)
         where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>;
}

class Test
{
    void Test(IQueryProcessor p)
    {
        var query = new SomeQuery();

        // Instead of
        // string result = p.Process<SomeQuery, string>(query);

        // You write
        string result;
        p.Process(query, out result);
    }
}
```

The only drawback I can think of is that it's prohibiting usage of 'var'.

Comment: you can have p.Process(query, out var result) as of C# 7.0

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround for this issue is to add additional parameter for type resolution.To avoid changes in existing codebase such parameter can be added to extension method. For instance you can add the following extension method:

```
static class QueryProcessorExtension
{
    public static TResult Process<TQuery, TResult>(
        this IQueryProcessor processor, TQuery query,
        //Additional parameter for TQuery -> IQuery<TResult> type resolution:
        Func<TQuery, IQuery<TResult>> typeResolver)
        where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
    {
        return processor.Process<TQuery, TResult>(query);
    }
}
```

Now we can use this extension as follows:

```
void Test(IQueryProcessor p)
{
    var query = new SomeQuery();

    //You can now call it like this:
    p.Process(query, x => x);
    //Instead of
    p.Process<SomeQuery, string>(query);
}
```

Which is far from ideal but much better than providing types explicitly.

P.S. Related links for this issue in dotnet repository:

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/997

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/7850

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a very old thread, and I don't know if the following snippet was valid ten years ago (`out var` surely not), but today it is compiling :

```
interface IQuery<TQuery, TResult>
{
}

interface IQueryProcessor
{
    void Process<TQuery, TResult>(IQuery<TQuery, TResult> query, out TResult result)
        where TQuery : IQuery<TQuery, TResult>;
    TResult ProcessAndReturn<TQuery, TResult>(IQuery<TQuery, TResult> query)
        where TQuery : IQuery<TQuery, TResult>;
}

class SampleQueryResult
{
}

class SampleQuery : IQuery<SampleQuery, SampleQueryResult>
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IQueryProcessor qp = null; // get it from di ?

        qp.Process(new SampleQuery(), out var r1);
        var r2 = qp.ProcessAndReturn(new SampleQuery());

        SampleQueryResult r;
        r = r1;
        r = r2;
    }
}
```

So today, there is no need to explicitly set the `TResult` type to use the `Process` method.

Comment: Your code compiled 10 years ago. This is because you changed the `IQuery<TResult>` to an `IQuery<TQuery, TResult>`. Your change is clever and solves the original problem. But unfortunately, it pushed the burden to the query implementations, which now all have to declare themselves. There's now some unfortunate redundancy. Whether this is acceptable is up to you. I myself rather have some extra complexity inside the query processor implementation, rather than having to complicate my query classes. Still, interesting solution.

Comment: OK thank you for your explanations. In my situation it is clearly preferable to place the redundancy at the level of the query declaration, because the equivalent of the Process method is called in multiple places, moreover the class representing the result is sometimes itself generic and complex, which makes the calling code difficult to write.