# C# resolve generic TOut from TIn

Tags: c#, .net, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t C# infer my generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511066/why-doesnt-c-sharp-infer-my-generic-types)

Let's say we have such a method and a class:

```
Result<TOut> SendMessage<TIn, TOut>(TIn message)
    where TIn : IMessage<TOut>
{
}

class Message : IMessage<string> 
{
}
```

Why can't it resolve types when I invoke it like so:

```
var message = new Message();
var result = SendMessage(message);
```

We have Tin and we have constraint on Tin, so from there we can know Tout. But why it's not working?

If I write

```
var result = SendMessage<Message, string>(message);
```

It obviously works, but this is not much convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [specification](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334%3a_25.6.4_Inference_of_type_arguments), type inference occurs on input parameters and not return types.

You can get around your issue by including the output generic type parameter in your argument list:

```
 public static Result<TOut> SendMessage<TOut>(IMessage<TOut> message)
```

Comment: That would fix this problem, but I need the Tin type for Service Locator to resolve IHandler<T> where T is type of a message.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is the syntax rule of Generic method. If you declare a method as Generic, you always need to provide the types when you invoke the method.

Comment: not true. `T Echo<T>(T input)` can be called as `Echo(1)` or `Echo("some string")`.