# Generic of generic type inference (request of response)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compiler-construction

I am currently working on a generic request / response abstraction to send arbitrary class requests to a component while receiving a pre-defined response class based on the request.

I have two base classes:

```
abstract class RequestClass<T>
    where T : ResponseClass
{
}

abstract class ResponseClass
{
}
```

A request class therefore defines its response class.
To demonstrate the situation I have the following example classes:

```
class DoSomethingRequest : RequestClass<DoSomethingResponse>
{
}

class DoSomethingResponse : ResponseClass
{
}
```

Now to process a request I have the following method:

```
TResult SendRequest<T, TResult>( T Request )
    where T : RequestClass<TResult>
    where TResult : ResponseClass
{
}
```

So far so good; however, while I expect the following to work, the compiler is not able to infer the type parameters for the following request:

```
DoSomethingResponse Response = SendRequest( new DoSomethingRequest() );
```

Why doesn't this work? The compiler should have all the information required do infer that "DoSomethingRequest is a RequestClass of DoSomethingResponse" and compile without a problem.
Is there any other way to get my scenario to work?

Help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance and best regards!
-Simon

Comment: What exception did you get?

Comment: Interesting question.  If you want this type of behavior without having to specify a generic type argument when you call your `SendRequest` method, why not create an overload that explicitly returns your expected type by calling the generic method and invoke the overload?

Comment: Identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511066/why-doesnt-c-sharp-infer-my-generic-types

Comment: It cannot infer the return type `TResult` it could be any class that inherits from `ResponseClass`