# Generic type specification arguments - sometimes optional, but not always

Tags: c#, generics

This question is about when you do and don't need to include generic type specification arguments. It's a bit lengthy, so please bear with it.

If you have the following (contrived) classes...

```
public abstract class UserBase
{
    public void DoSomethingWithUser() { }
}

public class FirstTimeUser : UserBase
{
     /* TODO: some implementation */
}
```

The following method...

```
private static void DoThingsWithUser<TUser>(TUser user) where TUser : UserBase
{
    user.DoSomethingWithUser();
}
```

Can be called with or without having to specify the type argument `TUser`...

```
var user = new FirstTimeUser();

DoThingsWithUser<FirstTimeUser>(user);
DoThingsWithUser(user); // also valid, and less typing required!
```

So far, so good.

But if you add a couple more (again, contrived) classes...

```
public abstract class UserDisplayBase<T> where T : UserBase
{
    public T User { get; protected set; }
}

public class FirstTimeUserDisplay : UserDisplayBase<FirstTimeUser>
{
    public FirstTimeUserDisplay()
    {
        User = new FirstTimeUser();
    }
}
```

And a method...

```
private static void DoThingsWithUserDisplay<TDisplay, TUser>(TDisplay userDisplay)
    where TDisplay : UserDisplayBase<TUser>
    where TUser : UserBase
{
    userDisplay.User.DoSomethingWithUser();
}
```

When calling this method, it is *mandatory* to include the type arguments...

```
var userDisplay = new FirstTimeUserDisplay();
DoThingsWithUserDisplay<FirstTimeUserDisplay, FirstTimeUser>(userDisplay); // Type arguments required!
```

If you don't specify the type arguments, you will get a compiler error of

> The type arguments for method 'DoThingsWithUserDisplay(TDisplay)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I *think* that the compiler should/could be smart enough to figure this out...or is there a subtle reason why not?

Comment: My guess is that the compiler couldn't do this for an interface using co/contravariance, and they didn't think it was worthwhile special-casing that and doing it in other situations.

Comment: This *might* be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511066/why-doesnt-c-sharp-infer-my-generic-types

Comment: @MatthewWatson - definitely a related question, but I'm wondering _why_ the compiler doesn't/can't infer the type arguments. Which I think is slightly different enough to prevent my question getting closed. :)

Comment: Yes, I didn't think it was a duplicate - just related enough to be of interest.

Comment: I'm willing to bet quite a bit of virtual money that [Eric Lippert's writeups on type inference](http://ericlippert.com/category/csharp/type-inference/) will somehow completely explain this after you've read all of them. Of course, I myself am too lazy to do this right now and construct the perfect answer from them... but who knows, maybe the master himself will grace us with his presence. :-)

Comment: Yes, this blog too: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the compiler is analyzing the types to infer, it reaches a dead end when looking at `DoThingsWithUserDisplay(userDisplay);`

It finds that `TDisplay` must be of type `FirstTimeUserDisplay`, which is good.  Then the constraint says that `TDisplay` must inherit from `UserDisplayBase<TUser>`.

Since it does not know the type for `TUser` it cannot determine if `FirstTimeUserDisplay` inherits from `UserDisplayBase<TUser>` and it also can't infer that the `TUser` parameter should whatever type is in the generic `UserDisplayBase<TUser>`.

Edit:
Incidentally, you can get the type inference you seek using an interface with a variant.  In this case, the interface definition provides sufficient inheritance information so that the constraints are met.

```
public abstract class UserDisplayBase<T> : IUserDisplayBase<T>
    where T : UserBase
{
    public T User { get; protected set; }
}

public interface IUserDisplayBase<out T>
    where T : UserBase
{
    T User { get; }
}

private static void DoThingsWithUserDisplay<TDisplay>(TDisplay userDisplay)
    where TDisplay : IUserDisplayBase<UserBase>
{
    userDisplay.User.DoSomethingWithUser();
}
```

can be called with

```
var userDisplay = new FirstTimeUserDisplay();
DoThingsWithUserDisplay(userDisplay);
```