# Generic arguments Auto-defining in methods

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I've got a generic command defenition with a single argument that returns some value

```
interface ICommand<Targ, TResult> {
    TResult Run(Targ argument);    
}
```

And I've got an interpreter with a generic method for that commands type

```
class Interpreter{
  public TResult Run<TCommand, TArg, TResult>(TArg arg) 
      where TCommand: ICommand<TArg, TResult>, new()
  {
      var cmd = new TCommand();
      return cmd.Run(arg);
  }
```

So i call these commands in a way like that

```
var interpreter = new Interpreter();
double converted = interpreter.Run<ConvertCommand, string, double>("123.5");
```

where

```
ConvertCommand: ICommand<string, double>
```

But i want to launch these commands in a minimalistic way

```
var interpreter = new Interpreter();
double converted = interpreter.Run<ConvertCommand>("123.5");
```

It seems that there enough generic type information for CLR for compiling that but it doesn't want to.

Is there any way to launch this type of generic methods with a single generic argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, generic type inference requires that method arguments provide the type for the arguments to let the compiler infer their generic types.

So only `TArg` could be infered, while `TResult` not. **In summary: no, you can't call a generic method without providing all generic arguments.**

### Possible alternative: refactor your code as follows...

I believe that I can give you a draft of what I would consider a better design in your case. Check the code and later I explain it bellow the sample:

```
public interface ICommand<TArg, TResult>
{
    TArg Arg { get; set; }
    TResult Run();
}

public sealed class ConvertCommand : ICommand<string, double>
{
    public string Arg { get; set; }

    public double Run()
    {
        return Convert.ToDouble(Arg);
    }
}

public static class CommandFactory
{
    public static TCommand Create<TCommand, TArg, TReturnValue>(TArg arg)
        where TCommand : ICommand<TArg, TReturnValue>, new ()
    {
        var cmd = new TCommand();
        cmd.Arg = arg;
        return cmd;
    }

    // This is like a shortcut method/helper to avoid providing 
    // generic parameters that can't be inferred...
    public static ConvertCommand ConvertCommand(string arg)
    {
        return Create<ConvertCommand, string, double>(arg);
    }
}

class Interpreter
{
    public TReturnValue Run<TArg, TReturnValue>(ICommand<TArg, TReturnValue> cmd)
    {
        return cmd.Run();
    }
}
```

I think that you shouldn't delegate the responsibility of building commands to the interpreter, but it should be a *command factory*. That is, the interpreter just run the command, gets command results, processes them, emits events... this is now up to you.

In the other hand, check that `Interpreter.Run` method receives an `ICommand<TArg, TReturn>` instead of a generic type parameter. This way, **both `TArg` and `TReturn` generic type arguments can be inferred from the `ICommand<TArg, TReturn>` from its implementation and you don't need to provide these generic arguments explicitly:

```
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
// TArg and TReturn are inferred!!
interpreter.Run(CommandFactory.ConvertCommand("0.1"));
```

Actually I would go with other designs/architectures in a real-world scenario, but I wanted to give you a hint on how to refactor your actual idea and let it work as you expect ;)

Comment: but i've got this information in IComand<T1,T2> defenition. There is no way to use it?

Comment: @tmt No.  [You can't partially infer generic arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8511493/1081897).  You can have the compiler infer all or none of them.

Comment: Sure, Thx. This is what i've tried to avoid.    instead of dirty 3-line construction with using, dirty creation synthax (new(), or, factory ). But life is imperfect. Almost as C#...

Comment: @tmt Well, C# is a strongly-typed language. If you can't guarantee typing during compile-time, C# can't guess what's in your mind. I believe that it's one of the most powerful language available today and it has an impressive feature set. IMHO, there're few cases where C# is the limitation: most of the times it's more about our mind: we've a toolset and we need to build software based on the tool. Sometimes imagination goes beyond of what's ever possible :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yes, # is the best. That example,contains full information types. As you need no to specify generic arguments in linq calling (where "specifying" object is argument) - also there are full information about types, but in calling generic first argument type. I see - there are no language constructions in c# that allow us to call some generics in a short way, if all generic arguments are related, but in theory it seems possible. Am i missed something?

Comment: @tmt It's harder than you imagine... Some human assumptions are hard to implement and cover every case without allowing dangerous programming practices...