# Result type covariance - generic class with method returning both an interface type and a specific type

Tags: c#, generics, interface, covariance

I've got these 2 interfaces:

```
public interface IResult
{
    object SomeProperty {get;set;}
}

public interface IFooManager
{
    IResult GetResult(string someId);
}
```

I'd like to implement an `IFooManager` in a generic class this way:

```
public class MyFooManager<T> : IFooManager where T: class, IResult
{
    public T GetResult(string id)
    {
        return null; //the value doesn't really matter here
    }
}
```

However, this results in a compilation error:

`Cannot implement method from interface [..].IFooManager. Return type should be [..].IResult`

Now, I know I could solve this by additionally defining the interface method explicitly, like this:

```
IResult IFooManager.GetResult(string id)
{
    return GetResult(id);
}
```

But the questions is: why can't the compiler just figure it out, that `T GetResult()` indeed returns an object implementing `IResult`? I know I could probably introduce an `out T` covariance interface on top of that, but I can't scratch it out of my head - why is the `T` type restriction not enough to ensure type safety?

Comment: There is no reason why return type covariance for function overriding couldn't be done by the compiler, except that the language doesn't support this (and it probably doesn't support it because the runtime doesn't support it). You could see this code working in other languages.

Comment: He can simply make his interface generic too, and have the method return T.

Comment: [Why doesn't C# infer my generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511066/why-doesnt-c-sharp-infer-my-generic-types)

Comment: @Mishka or actually implementing the interface (i.e. return IResult).

Comment: "But the questions is: why can't the compiler just figure it out, that T GetResult() indeed returns an object implementing IResult?" The signature simply doesn't match. Leaving generics out of it, if an interface method were declared to return `object`, would you expect to be able to implement it with a method declared to return `string`? Because that's never been the case.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I've completely messed it all up. Of course it's not generics-related at all, dummy me. All clear now, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because:

```
IResult GetResult(string someId);
```

is not the same as:

```
T GetResult(string id)
```

You told the compiler with the constraint that T is any class implementing `IResult` - not `IResult`. These 2 things are not the same.