# How to deduce the second generic parameter through the first generic parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following:

```
interface IGeneric<T> {}

class Test : IGeneric<int> {}

// in an unrelated class
public void foo<T, U>()
    where T : IGeneric<U>
{
    // do something
}
```

Now I want to call `foo` as follows: `foo<Test>()`. But with the code above, it doesn't work, since apparently I need to specify both parameters:

> ```
> Using the generic method 'MainClass.foo<T,U>()' requires 2 type arguments
> ```

Is there any way to make `foo<Test>()` work - preferably without having to pass a `Test` instance? The compiler should be able to deduce `U` (to `int` in this case).

Comment: The short answer is no. But you can define `public class FooInt<T>: foo<T,int>`

Comment: Is `foo` a member of `Test` class? Can you share a MCVE?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski No it's not. Does that help?

Comment: @Eldar Wait what is that? `foo` is a function, so not sure what that syntax is supposed to mean :)

Comment: I take it as a class definition :). Then the short answer is still valid.

Comment: @Eldar HOh yeah I get your point, that's a possible solution, not very useful if there are a lot of `U`s

Comment: The short answer was no :) not the derivation part.

Comment: @Eldar Oops my bad. Although your point is valid

Comment: Do you need to know the exact type of T? Could you rewrite it as `public void foo<U>()` and anywhere in the code you would have used `T` you instead use `IGeneric<U>`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That would work but `U` is an implementation detail so it's not great to have to specify it.

Comment: @Rakete1111 could you give some sense as to what `foo` would be doing and why it needs both type arguments?

The type inference infers based off of arguments. So, Something like this would infer the argument correctly, but requires input to the method `void Foo<U>(IGeneric<U> input)` `Foo(new Test())`

Comment: @BillKeller Mostly just nicer syntax. I'm currently using the `new Test()` approach like you say but I don't like it :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 I believe this is a similar discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511066/why-doesnt-c-sharp-infer-my-generic-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the language doesn't offer that. What you'd *like* the language to offer is a construct that lets you get hold of the  `U` from `T<U>` e.g.

```
public void foo<T> : where exists U : T is IGeneric<U>
public void foo<IGeneric<U>>()
```

But generic syntax is not that sophisticated. The nearest would be one of these:

```
public void foo<U>( IGeneric<U> t = null)
public void foo<U>( Test t = null)
```

Which are not what you want?

You **can** do it in code with an extra interface definition:

```
internal interface IGeneric { }
interface IGeneric<T> : IGeneric { }


public void foo<T>() where T : IGeneric
{
    var tGenericU= typeof(T)
                .GetInterfaces()
                .Where( i=> 
                           i.IsGenericType 
                        && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IGeneric<>) )
                .FirstOrDefault();
    Debug.Assert(typeofU != null);
    var typeofU= tGenericU.GetGenericArguments().First();             

    // do something
    Console.WriteLine( typeofU );
}
```