# In c# ,how to get type in complie time

Tags: c#, typeof

in Object-C, we can use typoef to get type in compile time , for example

```
Myclass *A = new A;
typeof(A) b = A;
```

is there something familiar in c#?

---

edit 1

what i want to to do

```
//i have a generic function like this, and i can't change it
T getV<T>(string parm)

// i have many members with different type in a class ClassUser
ClassA a;
ClassB b;
Action<int, string, LonglonglonglongClass> c;
...

// when i initialize a ClassUser,i had to write like this 
a = getV<ClassA>("a");
b = getV<ClassB>("b");
c = getV<Action<int, string, LonglonglonglongClass>>("c");
...

//  as you can see , it's annoying, i'd like to write like this
a = getV<typeof(a)>("a");
b = getV<typeof(b)>("b");
c = getV<typeof(c)>("c");
...
```

---

edit 2

find a workaround

```
// wrap the getV
void getV2<T>(string parm ,out T ret)
{
   ret = getV<T>(parm);
}

// write like this
getV2("a" ,out a);
```

Comment: You can always use `var B = A;`

Comment: It would help if you explain what you expect that code to do. Not many people are experts in both Object-C and C#... `typeof` is indeed answer to the question asked in title (and hence duplicate), but there is very good chance you are looking for something else. Some example of C# code you try to compile would be helpful too - not knowing type of an object at compile time is rare in C# (unless you do reflection) so it is possible there some more C#-ish solution to your actual problem. Please [edit] question to clarify so it potentially can be re-opened.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ,thanks ,i find a workaround

Comment: The answer that you've made part of question is standard solution (make return type as one of argument's types) for this as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511066/why-doesnt-c-sharp-infer-my-generic-types. Please make sure to clarify if you actually still have a question... (and what exactly it is as you seem to have code you are looking for already)

Comment: I think you need to clarify what this question is about. It sounds like to me that you're trying to write a factory method that can create new instances of a type that you have an existing instance of.

Answer (score 2):

```
Myclass A = new Myclass();

Type objectType = typeof(Myclass);
```

or

```
Type objectType = A.GetType();
```

Comment: thanks, but i want use type for template ,like ```Myclass A;

A = fun<typeof(A)>("some parm");```

Comment: If you want to use a generic type, you can make your class as a generic type like this: public class Myclass<T> and then get the type of T as a property of the class, like this: public Type PurposedType { get  {  return typeof(T);  } }